# Some Graphics Missed From Deepin

Tags: linux, qt, graphics, gnome, nautilus

I Have Deepin Linux (Based On Debian)

I Install A Package (Cutegram :|)

And Then I Delete It From My OS (apt-get remove cutegram)

But Then Some Graphical Packages Got Deleted With Cutegram

I Dont Know Where Else I Can See Damage Of It But

My File Manager (Nautilus) Loss Some Graphics And Got Ugly

(Sorry For My Bad English)

How Can I Fix It

Which Packages Should I Reinstall To Make It Work Well

Should I Install Things Like QT ???

Comment: please modify your spelling and provide some concrete message, like the pictures.

Comment: How can this question have an upvote? Flagged as very low quality